# upload images with html5's drag 'n' drop. server side?

Tags: html, upload, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a drag'n'drop code for uploading images. I'm a newbie on this technology/API.

I'm using the drag'n'drop API of the HTML5. I also use Apache as http server and node.js as websocket server. I found lots of tutorials for the client side implementation.

This is maybe a silly question, but what about the server side? I guess I have to implement a code on server side to handle the incoming image's upload and storage...

Any ideas?Or links?

Thanks

EDIT

I will use these APIs : drag'n'drop, FormData, XHR progress event and FileReader. I will create code based on [this](http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/) tutorial. I have not implemented anything specific yet, I'm still experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

The file saving on the server side is used as normally!

After using drag&drop you will get the file-objects in javascript and you can do what you want with them, either XHR-post them, use them in a normal form-POST or convert to a data-URI and post it to the server as base64 text.

i.e

```
element.ondrop = function(ev) {
    var files = ev.dataTransfer.files

    // post the files via XHR POST
    var formData = new FormData()

    // im lazy, use a supported loop
    for (file of files) {
        formData.append("file", file)
    }

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    req.open('POST', '/saveimage/')
    req.send(formData)

}
```

Will post the files just as you had used a normal non-drag and drop action.

For a better answer on how to save files we need some info about what language and framework your website uses.

Comment: Mentioning the language and framework I'm gonna use.Good idea, you are right. Sorry for that, I just edited my question.